# php rename() function returns "No such file or directory" error

Tags: php, function, for-loop

I have a folder with the several images in it.

The folder is `photos_1/130730782`

The images are

```
.jpg
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
6.jpg
```

I need to rename the file like this

```
.jpg  = 1.jpg
1.jpg = 2.jpg
2.jpg = 3.jpg
3.jpg = 4.jpg
4.jpg = 5.jpg
5.jpg = 6.jpg
6.jpg = 7.jpg
```

I'm using this code:

```
$sysid = '130730782';
    $dir = 'photos_1/'.$sysid;

    $myPhotoCount = iterator_count(new DirectoryIterator($dir)) - 1;

    for($i=0; $i<=count($myPhotoCount); $i++){
        $x = $i + 1;
        if($i == 0){
            rename("{$dir}/.jpg", "{$dir}/1.jpg");
        }else{
            rename("{$dir}/{$i}.jpg", "{$dir}/{$x}.jpg");
        }
    }
```

I get this error:

> Warning: rename(photos_1/130730782/.jpg,photos_1/130730782/1.jpg)
>   [function.rename]: No such file or directory in
>   /home/content/85/6608485/html/McCloskey/rename.php on line 18
>
> Warning: rename(photos_1/130730782/1.jpg,photos_1/130730782/2.jpg)
>   [function.rename]: No such file or directory in
>   /home/content/85/6608485/html/McCloskey/rename.php on line 20

I know the file exist, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Might be problem with file permissions.

Comment: Also could be an issue with relative paths?

Comment: photos_1 is in the same directory as rename.php

Comment: possibly try php exec() command: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to rename these files in reverse order.

If you rename .jpg to 1.jpg, then the original 1.jpg is possibly lost/overwritten.

Start with the highest number, and go backwards.

Comment: You're right about that, but it still doesn't solve the problem. I tried renaming them to numbers that don't exist in the folder and it still doesn't work.

Comment: True, but when you solve the file permission issue, this aspect of the code will need to change. Unused numbers will also work. Try PHP's exec() command to issue the rename via Linux and not PHP. Also verify that the strings being passed to the rename() function are indeed what you're expecting. (print_r() or something...)

Comment: i don't know Linux well enough to do that

Comment: (example) For issuing a linux command via PHP, you could try: exec("mv /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/test1.jpg /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/test2.jpg"); You might need to use absolute paths to the files.

Answer (score 1):

Remane it as the follows:

`.jpg --> 1.jpeg`

`1.jpg --> 2.jpeg`

and so on...

It would not make any change to your file as **JPG and JPEG are same** and there would be no lost/overwritting.

Comment: This approach may work, depending on how the .jpg files are used later on.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using copy() to just copy the files to another directory and renaming them in the process.